# Como não fazer nenhuma ação se o ternario caia no falso?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Quero que se o `selectedGenre` for diferente de vazio ou `null` ele execute `movie.genre === selectedGenre`, mas se for nulo ou vazio só saia da função sem retornar nada.

```
selectedGenre ? movie.genre === selectedGenre :
```

Comment: O operador ternário não deve ser usado como controle de fluxo.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Não fazendo um ternário, esse operador foi criado para dar um resultado, se não quer que seja feito um resultado o operador não deve ser usado, claramente é um caso para um `if`.

Mas se quiser insistir muito nisso, o que reforço ser um erro pode resultar em nulo:

```js
false ? console.log("ok") : null;
```

Mas não tem como fazer uma função encerrar sem fazer uma gambiarra maior ainda.

Forma correta e mais curta:

```js
if (false) console.log("ok");
```

E usando em função para dar a saída:

```js
function teste(valor) {
    if (valor) console.log("ok");
    else return;
    console.log("continuou");
}
teste(false);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/ExitConditional.js).

Quando deseja controlar o fluxo de execução o `if` é o correto. Operadores servem para gerar resultados, não controlar fluxo.

Answer (score 2):

No JavaScript não existe o tipo `void`, então a função, explicitamente ou não, irá retornar algo, se não for especificado, será `undefined`:

```js
function example() {}
console.log(example());

function example2() { return; }
console.log(example2());

const example3 = () => {};
console.log(example3());
```

Então você pode retornar `undefined` no terceiro operando do ternário ("`else`"):

```js
function example(bool) {
    return bool ? 'anything' : undefined;
}
console.log(example(true), example(false));

const example2 = (bool) => bool ? 'anything' : undefined;
console.log(example2(true), example2(false));
```

Uma outra forma de obter o valor undefined é utilizando a **operador** [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void):

```js
function example(bool) {
    return bool ? 'anything' : void 0;
}
console.log(example(true), example(false));

const example2 = (bool) => bool ? 'anything' : void 0;
console.log(example2(true), example2(false));
```

Ainda sim, concordo com a resposta anterior, o `if` é melhor pra esse objetivo, porém, em caso de *arrow functions* com uma única linha, afim de manter a simplicidade, faz sentido e é aceitável seu uso